# How are integers stored in the binary after compilation?

Tags: c, compilation

I am trying to create a program that can modify a compiled (or equivalent) file. The problem is to locate the different values in the compiled file, I manage to find string values but not integer values.

What I have done so far is that I take a compiled file as an input and produce a new file that is "human readable", basically I read the compiled file byte by byte and write each byte in the new file as a string of bits, for example a byte in the original file with value 124 becomes "01111100" in the new file. This seems to be working fine, I am able to do the reverse operation on the "human readable" file and run it.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For example, if I compile and translate the output file of the code above, I can find a sequence of bits corresponding to "Hello world!\n".

But in the code below, when translating the output file after compiling it, I can't find something corresponding to 3000 (whether I am looking for an Integer or a String corresponding to 3000).

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 3000;
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

My guess so far is that 3000 is written in a way I do not know about. Although it is equally possible that I'm doing something wrong in the translation process. So far I have tried to look for 3000 with the two following sequence of bits:

- As a Integer 00001011 10111000
- As a String 00110011 00110000 00110000 00110000

Edit: It may be important to underline that I compile with the no optimization flag -O0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably on an Intel machine which stores integers in little-endian order. You'd need to search for `10111000 00001011` (written in binary — the bytes in the reverse order from what you used before) or `0xB8 0x0B` in hex bytes.